# Superimpose a GeoGraphics Plot on Another

Tags: geographics

I'd like to superimpose a `GeoGraphics` image of Israel onto a `GeoGraphics` image of the United States in a manner that maintains appropriate scale. I tried

```
p1=GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Israel"]]]
p2=GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]]]
Show[p1,p2]
```

but this gives one image of the world with the US at left and Israel at right, with Europe, Greenland, Africa, etc., all shown in between.

How can I put a scaled image of Israel onto the US? Ideally, I'd like to put it somewhere along the eastern coast, as that's where I'm from. I'm trying to show the relative sizes of the countries.

Comment: Does [How can I show the relative size of two GeoGraphics objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125660/41569) do what you need? (possibly a duplicate)

Comment: GeoGraphics image showing Israel on the eastern U.S. [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqtZN.png)

Comment: @creidhne Thanks for the link to the other post. I wasn't sure what to search for to answer my question, and all my queries fell short.